# Continous Integration on VSTS broken after installing most recent Service Fabric SDK

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I've configured my VSTS Continous Integration in a similar way that is described here: https://azure.microsoft.com/pl-pl/documentation/articles/service-fabric-set-up-continuous-integration/. Unfortunately, after installing most recent version of Azure Service Fabric SDK 2.1.150, my "Build" step stopped working. I'm receiving following error:

`The OutputPath property is not set for project 'ServiceFabricProjectName.sfproj'. Please check to make sure that you have specified a valid combination of Configuration and Platform for this project. Configuration='Release' Platform='x64'. You may be seeing this message because you are trying to build a project without a solution file, and have specified a non-default Configuration or Platform that doesn't exist for this project.`

From what I've seen, during project migration to most recent version there have been following changes done to *.sfproj file:

- Added project import for Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.MSBuild.1.1.0
- Added following items:
  `<ItemGroup Label="ProjectConfigurations">
      <ProjectConfiguration Include="Debug|x64">
        <Configuration>Debug</Configuration>
        <Platform>x64</Platform>
      </ProjectConfiguration>
      <ProjectConfiguration Include="Release|x64">
        <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
        <Platform>x64</Platform>
      </ProjectConfiguration>
  </ItemGroup>`
- Added couple of other project imports. One of them are targets from Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.MSBuild.1.1.0 package.

Strange thing is that, when I log onto build agent virtual machine, and run the solution within Visual Studio from C:\agent_work\1\s\ProjectName and change the build configuration to Release | x64, I'm able to build it. When I disable "git clean -fdx" step in VSTS, all following CI builds will succeed. It looks really strange and with previous version of Service Fabric SDK everything worked fine.

Has anyone observed similar issues?

Comment: Are you restoring NuGet packages in your build definition?  Are you seeing in the build log that the Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.MSBuild package is being restored?

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue if anyone solves it

Comment: Actually, this is a dotnet core project and I included "dotnet restore" step, without old fashion NuGet package restore. When I've added this step, the problem stopped occuring, but now I'm facing some other error: CS0006: Metadata file could not be found. But I'm not sure if it's related to this problem. Anyway - thank you @MattThalman for response!

Answer (score 0):

I have found this with any SF project where the project is not immediately under the solution. In vs as well msbuild bug for fsproj I'd say